# AWS CDK error creating an ARecord for CloudFront distro

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53, aws-cdk

Given:
export class MyARecord extends cdk.Stack {
public readonly arecord: ARecord

```
constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props: IcARecordARecordProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const hostedZone = HostedZone.fromHostedZoneAttributes(this, 'hostedZone', {
        hostedZoneId: props.hostedZoneId,
        zoneName: props.apexDomainName
    })

    console.log(hostedZone.hostedZoneId);
    console.log(hostedZone.zoneName);

    const distribution = Distribution.fromDistributionAttributes(this, 'distribution', {
        domainName: props.apexDomainName,
        distributionId: props.distributionId
    });

    this.arecord = new ARecord(this, `${props.projectName}ARecord`, {
        zone: hostedZone,
        target: RecordTarget.fromAlias(
            new CloudFrontTarget(distribution)
        )
    })
}
```

}

Deploying I get the following logging and error:
hostedZoneId: 'Z1016966FIW9RVHP46ST',
zoneName: 'testmyroute53domain.com',

08:21:59 | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::Route53::RecordSet | testmyroute53domaincomARecordB9B947F2
[Tried to create an alias that targets testmyroute53domain.com., type A in zone Z2FDTNDATAQYW2, but the alias target name does not lie within the target zone]

Anybody have any idea why it asks about a zone 'Z2FDTNDATAQYW2' when the zone id is clearly 'Z1016966FIW9RVHP46ST'?

Manually I made the A record and it works.... Just AWS CDK does not want to create it for me...